Flutter go_router custom transition to a NavBar wrapped in StatefulShellRoute
I have 4 routes all on the same level: '/welcome', '/login', StatefulShellRoute('/tab1', '/tab2'), which I consider 3 discreet sections of the app.
I don't want any animation when going between sections ('/welcome', '/login', '/tab1'). While it was easy to achieve for '/welcome' and '/login' with a CustomTransitionPage, I cannot customize the transition between '/login' and '/tab1' because '/tab1' is wrapped in StatefulShellRoute.
I tried to follow this example using navigatorContainerBuilder, but that seems to only customize the transition when going between tabs and not from '/login' to '/tab1'.
Is there a way to customize the transition from '/login' to '/tab1'? OR, is there a way to globally customize transitions any time go_router calls navigator.replace()?
Couldn't upload a .gif so it is linked here.
Below is the code to reproduce my issue:
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _rootNavigatorKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'root');
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _firstTabNavigatorKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'tab1Nav');

final _router = GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  initialLocation: '/welcome',
  debugLogDiagnostics: true,
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
        name: 'Welcome',
        path: '/welcome',
        pageBuilder: (context, state) => opacityTransition(state, Welcome()),
        routes: []),
    GoRoute(
      name: 'Login',
      path: '/login',
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => opacityTransition(state, Login()),
    ),
    StatefulShellRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state,
            StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell) {
          return navigationShell;
        },
        navigatorContainerBuilder: (BuildContext context,
            StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell, List<Widget> children) {
          return ScaffoldWithNavBar(
              navigationShell: navigationShell, children: children);
        },
        branches: <StatefulShellBranch>[
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _firstTabNavigatorKey,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: '/tab1',
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    const Tab1Root(),
                // pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
                //     opacityTransition(state, Tab1Root()),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellBranch(
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                  path: '/tab2',
                  builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                      const Tab2Root()),
            ],
          ),
        ])
  ],
);

class AppNavigator extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppNavigator({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}

CustomTransitionPage opacityTransition(GoRouterState state, Widget child) {
  return CustomTransitionPage(
    key: state.pageKey,
    child: child,
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      return FadeTransition(
        opacity: CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOutCirc).animate(animation),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}

// ScaffoldWithNavbar

class ScaffoldWithNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScaffoldWithNavBar({
    required this.navigationShell,
    required this.children,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key ?? const ValueKey<String>('ScaffoldWithNavBar'));

  final StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell;

  final List<Widget> children;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnimatedBranchContainer(
        currentIndex: navigationShell.currentIndex,
        children: children,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Section A'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.work), label: 'Section B'),
        ],
        currentIndex: navigationShell.currentIndex,
        onTap: (int index) => navigationShell.goBranch(index),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onTap(BuildContext context, int index) {
    navigationShell.goBranch(
      index,
      initialLocation: index == navigationShell.currentIndex,
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedBranchContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const AnimatedBranchContainer(
      {super.key, required this.currentIndex, required this.children});

  final int currentIndex;

  final List<Widget> children;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
        children: children.mapIndexed(
      (int index, Widget navigator) {
        return Visibility(
          visible: index == currentIndex,
          child: _branchNavigatorWrapper(index, navigator),
        );
      },
    ).toList());
  }

  Widget _branchNavigatorWrapper(int index, Widget navigator) => IgnorePointer(
        ignoring: index != currentIndex,
        child: TickerMode(
          enabled: index == currentIndex,
          child: navigator,
        ),
      );
}

// Views

class Welcome extends StatelessWidget {
  const Welcome({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Welcome'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Sign in'),
          onPressed: () => context.go('/login'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Login'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Login'),
          onPressed: () => context.go('/tab1'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Tab1Root extends StatelessWidget {
  const Tab1Root({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Tab 1'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Tab 1'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Tab2Root extends StatelessWidget {
  const Tab2Root({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Tab 2'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Logout'),
          onPressed: () => context.go('/welcome'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I tired CustomTransitionPage and navigatorContainerBuilder.
